# How to search an entered message for four keywords

Tags: python, string

Basically I have a task set for me in Python. It is to search for these 4 keywords: **bomb, nuclear, terrorist and gordon brown,** within a imputed message. I then have to output whether it is a '**SAFE**' message or an '**UNSAFE**' message.

So far this is what I got (I am a bit of a noob at Python. I'm still learning the language.):

```
keyWord = "bomb"
keyWord1 = "nuclear"
keyWord2 = "terrorist"
keyWord3 = "gordon brown"

def textSearch():
    message = input("Input a message: ")
    if message == keyWord + keyWord1 + keyWord2 + keyWord3:
        print("This is message is UNSAFE!")
    else:
        print("This is a SAFE message.")

textSearch()
```

Please help!

It works if I type in just one of the words. But it doesn't work when I try to search a whole message for the keyword.

Comment: `if keyword in message or keyword1 in message` etc.

Comment: Beware of the [Scunthorpe problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently looking for the specific message:

"bombnuclearterroristgordon brown"

What you want to use is `in` which will find a substring within your string.  Do this with each keyword:

```
if keyWord in message:
    #keyWord exists in message
```

It would be easier if you put your keywords in a list, then you can loop them:

```
keywords = ["bomb", "nuclear", "terrorist", "gordon brown"]

for keyword in keywords:
    if keyword in message:
        #Bad message!
```

Even tidier would be to use a list comprehension and the `any()` function, which achieves the same as the above in a single line:

```
bad = any(keyword in message for keyword in keywords)
```

Alternatively, if you need to do something with the location of the substrings, then you can use `find()` which returns an index to the location of the first match:

```
position = message.find(keyword) 
if position > -1:
    #Bad message
```

Comment: Just curious: Any particular reason you favor `find` over `in`?

Comment: Nope, just force of habit.  `in` is nicer (as he doesn't require the position of the substring) so I'll swap it over in my answer.

Comment: Well, in 2005, `find` was much faster than `in` when the string was not found. I hope that's no longer true. :) http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-February/051602.html

Comment: Yeah that would make my life a lot easier aha.

Comment: `any(word in message for word in keywords)`

Comment: Good call @katrielalex - I've added that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
message == keyWord + keyWord1 + keyWord2 + keyWord3
```

This will be True iff `message` is exactly equal to 'bombnuclearterroristgordon brown'. You probably want to use the `in` operator to check for membership.

```
keyWord in message or keyWord1 in message or keyWord2 in message or keyWord3 in message
```

… that's obviously cumbersome, but you have nice alternatives with Python. Start by making a list of keywords instead of individual names:

```
keyWords = ["bomb", "nuclear", "terrorist", "gordon brown"]
```

then, use a list comprehension:

```
if [keyWord in message for keyWord in keyWords]:
    …
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of my lesson I once had in class. I remember doing something like this in my class.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a list of 'forbidden' keywords like this:

```
keywords = ["bomb", "nuclear", "terrorist"]
```

And then you could iterate of them and check whether they are contained in the text like this:

```
for keyword in keywords:
    if keyword in message:
        print "unsafe"
        break
```

`break` is being used to stop iterating over keywords after the first occurence of one of them is found.

You also could do it by a list comprehension like this:

```
if [keyword in message for keyword in keywords]...
```

But I think the former solution is easier to understand for you as Python beginner.

Comment: Yeah I remember doing something like this once before. Thank you for your help. This makes my life a lot easier aha. :)

Comment: Glad to have helped you, keep coding :-)